# How to control attributes with roles in CHEF

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

How to change the attribute values defined in a cookbook using roles.

Use Case:

I have a cookbook

```
mkdir
├── Berksfile
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── attributes
│   └── attribute.rb
├── chefignore
├── metadata.rb
├── recipes
│   └── default.rb
├── spec
│   ├── spec_helper.rb
│   └── unit
│       └── recipes
│           └── default_spec.rb
└── test
    └── integration
    └── default
        └── default_test.rb
```

In the attribute.rb i have the following:

node.override['main']['directory'] = "rolesquestionserverA"

## node.default['main']['directory'] = "rolesquestionserverA"

In the recipe/default.rb i have the following

```
bash 'extract_module' do
  code <<-EOH
    mkdir -p /tmp/#{node['main']['directory']}
    EOH
end
```

Now on Server A i want a directory created with rolesquestionserverA

and on Server B I want a directory createdrolesquestionserverB"

In the Roles directory i have the following contents:\

```
name "mkdir"
description "An example Chef role"
run_list "recipe[mkdir]"
override_attributes({
   #"starter_name" => "Test  ",
   "directory" => "rolesquestionserverB"
})
```

I have added this role to the recipe only for Server B but when it is run on Server B it is not overwritten but simply creates a directory with the same name as in the cookbook and not in the role
How can i control it with Roles & Attributes?? or is there a better way to achieve this??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`"main"` is not appended to the top level of your attributes structure. You have to always use the full path.

Your override attributes should look like:

```
override_attributes({
   "main" => {
      "directory" => "rolesquestionserverB"
   }
})
```

Have you considered using [the directory resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_directory.html)? Putting execute/bash/script in each example does not make much sense and it is not the best use of Chef.